# Using native MySQL funciton in active records (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get all data which date is greater than or equal to today.
Here is what I do:

```
$this->db->select('id, name');
$this->db->where('dr', '1');
$this->db->where('end >=', 'CURDATE()');
$query = $this->db->get('store');
```

But it doesen't work. What I wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Active Records automatically escapes your query, so CURDATE() will be passed as a string instead of using the mysql function.
You'd better off runing your query manually, something like

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,name FROM store WHERE dr = '1' AND end >= CURDATE()");
```

**Or** if you still want to use AR, **you could pass a FALSE as third parameter** of `$this->db->where` to avoid automatic escaping by CI:

```
$this->db->select('id,name')
         ->where('dr','1')
         ->where('end >=', 'CURDATE()', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('store');
```

Comment: it should be NOW() for the timestamp type

Answer (score 3):

I don't use active records in CI but I would guess that `CURDATE()` is being put in a string in the query so it's doing `WHERE end >= 'CURDATE()'` as opposed to `WHERE end >= CURDATE()`

If `end` is a timestamp field try...

```
$this->db->where('end >=', time());
```

If `end` is a datetime field try...

```
$this->db->where('end >=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```