# Get records having current datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

In db I have a field with data type **datetime** and it saves data like

`2000-10-30 13:39:27`

```
2013-10-30 13:39:27
```

now I tried

```
select * from my_table where published = CURDATE()
```

and

```
select * from my_table where published = NOW()
```

but no record found.

And how to use it with CodeIgnter active record. I tried

`$this->db->where("date(published)", "CURDATE()");`

but no row return

Comment: Here I found the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900218/using-native-mysql-funciton-in-active-records-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You can etract the `date` of a `datetime` with `date()`

```
select * from my_table 
where date(published) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: and do you know how to use it with CodeIgnter active record.

i tried $this->db->where("date(published)", "CURDATE()"); but no row return

Comment: @PHPFerrari: Sorry, I am not familiar with CodeIgnator.